# Is there a way to install Firefox OS in Windows Phone?

Tags: lumia, nokia-lumia-530

I have a Nokia Lumia 530 Dual Sim and I want to install another OS, Firefox OS specifically, but I don't know if it will be possible. I've found some tutorials for Samsung Galaxy phones, but not for Nokias.

Is it possible?

Comment: Firefox OS is a discontinued product. You will hardly find any support for it. Why are you interested in it?

Comment: I just wanted to have a taste of it...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in webmags (e.g. [TheVerge](https://www.theverge.com/2015/12/8/9872802/mozilla-has-killed-the-firefox-phone)) Firefox OS will be discontinued. WP are not really made to be hacks.
Take a look on [OnePlus](http://oneplus.net) side.